# Get HTTP Text from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, tcp

How do you get the full HTTP text from JavaScript? I'm talking about the thing that looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 04:03:27 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<html>
    ....
</html>
```

JavaScript provides nice high-level functions for headers, status codes, etc., but something is going wrong with an external server and I need direct access to the text exactly as it's sent over TCP.

Here's the relevant code:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
    // TODO: get HTTP response text
};
xhr.open('GET', '/');
xhr.send();
```

I'm looking for a programmatic solution; I can't just "look at the dev tools" because I need to parse the full HTTP response text as part of my application.

Comment: Depends how request is made. Not enough known

Comment: How can it depend on the request? I'm making a generic XMLHttpRequest and I'd like the full HTTP text of the response.

Comment: OK..well there are other ways beyond `XMLHttpRequest`. Can inspect it right in browser dev tools network if that helps. Otherwise show relevant code

Comment: Updated the question description with context.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exact solution you are looking for. But this might help you

```
fetch("<your-url>")
.then(function(resp){
    resp.headers.forEach(function(v,h){
        console.log(h,":",v);
    });
    return resp.text();
})
.then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
})
```

Comment: This is better than nothing, but is there a way to get the full header list? (Some headers aren't available in resp.headers).

Comment: Yea some headers like set-cookie are missing. refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name